# How to prove that the first $43$ digits of $43!$ is a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I saw this problem posted by someone in twitter , and this really just boggled up my mind .

Check this here:- https://twitter.com/fermatslibrary/status/1235215179115360257/photo/1

Now i am really thinking , how can I ever prove this fact ?
Any ideas ?

Also the next number n by which the first $n$ digits of $n!$ is prime is $93$ .

Comment: Look at [OEIS A060323](https://oeis.org/A060323).

Comment: The straightforward way to "prove" it is to write a computer program that checks if it is prime. Of course, since it is a huge number, you'll have to think of a clever design if you want that program to give an answer before the extinction of the sun.

Comment: @OlivierRoche ??  43! = 60415263063373835637355132068513997507264512000000000 its not that big a number (Checked with wolframalpha, the first 43 digits is a prime number https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6041526306337383563735513206851399750726451+is+prime )

Comment: turns out the wolframalpha check may be probabalistic https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132670/some-information-about-primeq-function

Comment: @HBrown What I meant is that one can't use the naive algorithm that takes all odd numbers $\leqslant \sqrt{6041526306337383563735513206851399750726451}$ and checks one by one if they divide our 43 digits number.

Comment: $93$ is not prime.

Comment: Aha True , it need not be prime numbers though .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this deals with extracting a number from a specific representation (base ten), I'd expect it to be a "by accident" type result that can be checked but has no simple "reason" that leads to an elegant proof.

As @OlivierRoche points out, we will have to turn to some sophisticated primality testing if we want to do this in a reasonable amount of time. So depending on your comfort of using computers in a proof, here's a demonstration with Mathematica

```
In[1]: << PrimalityProving`
In[2]: 43!
60415263063373835637355132068513997507264512000000000
In[3]: ProvablePrimeQ[6041526306337383563735513206851399750726451, "Certificate"->True]
{True, {6041526306337383563735513206851399750726451, 
  2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2}}, {973487, 
    5, {2, {107, 
      2, {2, {53, 2, {2, {13, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}}}, {4549, 
      6, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {379, 
        2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {7, 
          3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}}}}}, {538874068398317, 
    2, {2, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {197, 
      2, {2, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}, {97692905801, 
      3, {2, {5, 2, {2}}, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {41, 
        6, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}, {1701967, 
        5, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {827, 
          2, {2, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {59, 
            2, {2, {29, 
              2, {2, {7, 
                3, {2, {3, 
                  2, {2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}, {76778207814830066617, 
    13, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {31, 
      3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2}}}}, {85627, 
      2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {67, 
        2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {11, 2, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}}}, {71, 
        7, {2, {5, 2, {2}}, {7, 
          3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}}}, {1205186633657, 
      3, {2, {197, 2, {2, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}, {6029, 
        2, {2, {11, 2, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}, {137, 
          3, {2, {17, 3, {2}}}}}}, {126839, 
        11, {2, {63419, 
          2, {2, {37, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {857, 
            3, {2, {107, 
              2, {2, {53, 
                2, {2, {13, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

The certificate can in principle be checked with a simpler program, to verify the computation was correct.

Further details here:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PrimalityProving/tutorial/PrimalityProving

EDIT: More details about the certificate for those curious
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110549/what-is-the-form-of-a-primalityprovingprimeqcertificate

Comment: [OEIS A060323](https://oeis.org/A060323) lists that this works for 43, 93, 808, 2057, 3247, 13557 (above 30000 unknown).  It is quick to check 43 and 93, but 808 and on I was only able to check with probabilistic primality tests (which since those have no false negatives, I can also verify no missing numbers in that list up to 20,000 at least).