# Likelihood that first n digits of n! form a prime number

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

[OEIS A060323](https://oeis.org/A060323) is the sequence of numbers such that "The first n digits of n! form a prime number."

Let $f(n)$ = the integer given by the first n digits of n!, which is defined on $n \ge 22$ to ensure that n! has at least n digits.

Already at n = 22, n! has quite a few zeros from all the factors of 2 and 5. And due to all the even numbers in the product, the lowest non-zero digit will always be even. Including any of these digits ensures $f(n)$ is not prime. The lowest value where n! is large enough so that the first n digits do not include these is when n=42.

So, when is $f(n)$ prime?
Surprisingly, almost as soon as it is possible, we get a prime.
The currently known values are: 43, 93, 808, 2057, 3247, 13557 (above 30000 unknown).

Note that right off the bat we are talking about numbers with over 40 digits, so one estimate for the probability of $f(n)$ being a prime is $(1/\log f(n)) \approx (1/ \log 10^n) = (1 / n \log 10)$.

Then the expected number of primes below $N$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
m &\approx \sum_{42 \le n \le N} \frac{1}{n \log 10} \\
&\approx \frac{1}{\log 10} \int_{42}^N dn \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \frac{1}{\log 10} (\log N - \log 42)
\end{aligned}
$$

But if I plug in $N = 30000$, I get the expected number of primes is 2.854. Which is more than a factor of 2 off from what we see!

For something starting with tens of digits going up through thousands of digits, I'm surprised the estimate is so far off. And if anything, I was expecting an over estimate, with possible more reasons to eliminate the smaller values as composite.

Is there a missing factor in my calculation?
What is going on here that is pushing up the likely hood of being prime?

At the very least, is this estimate reasonable evidence there are an infinite number of $f(n)$ which are prime, because the sum diverges as $N \to \infty$ ?

Comment: This is a follow up to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632773/how-to-prove-that-the-first-43-digits-of-43-is-a-prime-number